# When to kill a running script R

Tags: r

I am having a larger data set with more than 1 million entries. If I am running scripts it sometimes takes up a while till I get an output. Sometimes it seems that there is no output what so ever, even if I let it run for hours. Is there a way to track the progress of the computation (or maybe just see if it is not stuck)?

Answer (score 2):

**1. Start small**

Write your analysis script and then test it using trivially small amounts of data. Gradually scale up and see how the runtime increases. The `microbenchmark` package is great at this. In the example below, I compare the amount of time it takes to run the same function with three different sized chunks of data.

```
library(microbenchmark)

long_running_function <- function(x) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {
        Sys.sleep(0.01)
    }
}

microbenchmark(long_running_function(mtcars[1:5,]), 
                             long_running_function(mtcars[1:10,]), 
                             long_running_function(mtcars[1:15,]))
```

**2. Look for functions that provide progress bars**

I'm not sure what kind of analysis you're performing, but some packages already have this functionality. For example, `ranger` gives you more updates than the equivalent `RandomForest` functions.

**3. Write your own progress updates**

I regularly add `print()` or `cat()` statements to large code blocks to tell me when R has finished running a particular part of my analysis. Functions like `txtProgressBar()` let you add your own progress bars to functions as well.

Comment: When iterating through something (even with apply), I notice that using print or cat to show the iteration really slows down over time. It seems to me that for that the progress bar is preferable.

Comment: Definitely. `print()` and `cat()` are more useful for things like "The data collection chunk has finished running"